# Using inline javascript correctly

Tags: javascript, function, push-notification, onclick, inline

I'm using a service called OneSignal to deliver push notifications to desktop and mobile devices. I'm trying to use a button element to trigger some inline javascript which is an option directly available for this element as the button allows an inline onclick javascript event to be specified. The javascript I've been given by the development team is below:

```
var OneSignal = OneSignal || []; OneSignal.push(function() { OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications(); });
```

Which I have added to the element but doesn't seem to be functioning. They also provided me with a redirect function for successful subscription:

```
var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];
OneSignal.push(function() {
OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function(isSubscribed) {
if (isSubscribed) {
  location.href = "http://redirecturlhere.com";
}
});
});
```

The button element is part of Visual Composer:

[View button element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryIaM.png)

Although my knowledge of CSS/html is good, my javascript knowledge leaves much to be desired. I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction or point out anything in the code or the way I have applied the code that could be hindering this functionality from working.

Answer (score 0):

```
OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function(isSubscribed)
```

Usually the `subscriptionChange` refers to either an ID of an element or a Class.

try **#subscriptionChange** which means it's an ID usually otherwise try **.subscriptionChange** since the period usually denotes a class.

Answer (score 0):

In JS when closing parentheses or a function in-line, you do not add the semicolons, so it would end up like this:

```
var OneSignal=OneSignal||[];OneSignal.push(function(){OneSignal.on("subscriptionChange",function(a){a&&(location.href="http://redirecturlhere.com")})});
```